# Create memcached service in windows failed

Tags: windows-services, memcached

I'm using `Memcached-for-Windows`, see:

http://blog.elijaa.org/index.php?post/2010/08/25/Memcached-1.4.5-for-Windows&similar

I've tried to use:

```
sc create "memcached" binPath="C:/memcached/mem
cached.exe" start=auto
```

but I can't create the Windows service, and no warning or error, just:

```
Creates a service entry in the registry and Service Database.
SYNTAX:
sc create [service name] [binPath= ] <option1> <option2>...
CREATE OPTIONS:
NOTE: The option name includes the equal sign.
type= <own|share|interact|kernel|filesys|rec>
   (default = own)
 start= <boot|system|auto|demand|disabled>
   (default = demand)
 error= <normal|severe|critical|ignore>
       (default = normal)
 binPath= <BinaryPathName>
 group= <LoadOrderGroup>
 tag= <yes|no>
 depend= <Dependencies(separated by / (forward slash))>
 obj= <AccountName|ObjectName>
       (default = LocalSystem)
 DisplayName= <display name>
 password= <password>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

memcached isn't a native Windows Service so you must use a "service wrapper" program to add the missing functionality. [Microsoft's free Srvany utility](http://www.coretechnologies.com/WindowsServices/FAQ.html#WhatIsSrvany) should do the trick but several commercial alternatives are also available.

(Note that some Windows ports of memcached support the "-d" flag to automatically install and manipulate memcached as a native Windows Service but that doesn't seem to be available in NorthScale's version...)

Answer (score 9):

To implement this, you can even execute a command line, which inturn creates a service.
First go to the path where the .exe file exists through command line.

```
C:\Users\sireesh.yarlagadda>memcached.exe -d install
```

After executing this line, you will be seeing a new service created for memcached

Comment: Yes!

`memcached.exe -d install` then 
`memcached.exe -d start`

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're getting an error is that there must be a space after the binPath= . This is a very annoying 'feature' of sc. Also you'd need a space after the start=.

```
sc create "memcached" binPath= "C:/memcached/memcached.exe" start= auto
```

The above command wouldn't give you the syntax error. However, I suspect memcached still won't run successfully as a service.

Answer (score 0):

You can build Memcached on Windows.

http://vasil9v.tumblr.com/post/31921755331/compiling-memcached-on-cygwin-windows